System data takes up over 300 GB, how can I clean my system data?
On my MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020) running Sonoma 14.6.1, system data takes up over 300 GB, see screenshot below.
How can I delete all of this data?



Apple defines "System Data" as "everything else that's not in the other categories", which is not very helpful. It could literally be anything. As said: use one of the apps that sort your drive by size and show you what's taking the space.
